# where should I place a parent pom?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I read about creating parent POM files but I don't know where to place it ?
I use Jfrog Artifactory server free edition.

Comment: Now I understand that parent POM file is just a pom file with Packaging set to "POM" and after creating them we can deploy them to any repository.

Answer (score 2):

You build a parent POM as a Maven project with packaging `pom` and run `mvn clean deploy` to deploy it on your Artifactory server.

Comment: above cmd is enough? or any extra conf is required? I thought that with `deploy` it will save on local repo..

Comment: `install` is for local repo, `deploy` for remote repo.

Comment: what about distributionmanagement? is it not required

Comment: `<distributionManagement>` defines where the `deploy` command actually sends the artifacts.

Comment: I want to deploy parent `pom` (all dependencies) into artifactory with child-specific dependencies (no child `war` deployment) is there any example. currently, I'm uploading the local repository manually into artifactory

Comment: @nay Sorry, cannot follow you. It would be best to just open a new question where you describe in detail what you want and what problems arise.